# как кликнуть по кнопке с классом,если их несколько?

Tags: javascript

```js
document.querySelector('.alert').click();
```

```html
<button class='alert' onclick='alert("клик на 1 кнопку")'> 1 кнопка</button>
<button class='alert' onclick='alert("клик на 2 кнопку")'> 2 кнопка</button>
<button class='alert' onclick='alert("клик на 3 кнопку")'> 3 кнопка</button>
```

но он нажимает на первую кнопку,а не на вторую.

Comment: присвоить кнопке `id` например `<button id="button2" class='alert' onclick='alert("клик на 2 кнопку")'> 2 кнопка</button>` и в скрипте прописать 
 нажатие `document.getElementById('button2').click(); `

Comment: @arendach присвоить не могу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.querySelector('')` хватает первый элемент

```js
// или по идексу или прокручивать в цикле
document.getElementsByClassName('alert')[1].click();

//
```

```html
<button class='alert' onclick='alert("клик на 1 кнопку")'> 1 кнопка</button>
<button class='alert' onclick='alert("клик на 2 кнопку")'> 2 кнопка</button>
<button class='alert' onclick='alert("клик на 3 кнопку")'> 3 кнопка</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

var second = document.querySelector(".alert:nth-of-type(2)")
console.log(second)